# How to calls a swift function on button click on a webview in iOS?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to click a button on a webview which calls a `swift` function. I can't figure it out. I know how to do `swift` to `js` call from swift but not the other way around.

```
self.webVw.evaluateJavaScript("callNativeApp()", completionHandler: { (obj, error) in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        else
        {
            print("Object : \(String(describing: obj))")
            self.testData()
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that's not possible.

Detailed answer is there are alternate ways to achieve something like this. You have to redirect to another page, and using WebView delegates handle your logic. You can also send a push notification from server which does something in your app or finally you can open Universal Link if that's an option.